# Расшифровать гео метки ВК

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, yandex-geocoding-api

[image: Скрин с Page Source поста VK]

Как расшифровать `geohash` из постов ВК, которые содержат гео метку?

Comment: А зачем? Плюс этот geohash не имеет отношения к API Карт, это какая-то внутренняя вконтактовская штука. Вы можете просто геокодировать адрес, который там в явном виде передан (только без показа карты можно использовать только платный геокодер)

Answer (score 2):

Не обязательно использовать именно `geohash` из кода элемента страницы. Можно использовать `API VK`, на поможет метод [`wall.getById`](https://vk.com/dev/wall.getById)

Указываем данные параметры, и получаем результат в формате `json`

`posts` `=` `-40033745_4` (в моем случае пример записи), где:
`-40033745` - идентификатор сообщества, а `4` идентификатор записи

Ждем **выполнить**, и получаем следующее

*(все нужные данные **подчеркнуты** красным)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ответе нам сервер вернул параметр `geo`, в котором вся информация о гео-локации записи.

Comment: Let's say Pie Спасибо большое за ваш ответ. Это точно то что мне нужно. Если у меня большое количество постов, мне нужна специальное приложение для обработки запросов? Извиняюсь, если задаю очень простые вопросы. Что советуете прочитать, чтобы разобраться во всем ?

Comment: @Владимир, если постов не так уж и много, то можно передать данные в `posts` нескольких записей (через запятую), например, `-40033745_4, -40033745_5, -62579072_384216` и так далее, но если записей много, то лучше написать какой-нибудь скрипт с циклом, так будет куда проще. Рад был помочь, спрашивайте если нужно, можете и верным ответом поставить, если хотите :D